# How to set request headers in WordPress Rest API calls

Tags: php, api, rest, wordpress

Hi am new to WP development, I would like to add request headers to WordPress Rest API calls but don't know how, can anyone help me in this?

I tried following code but no luck

```
$args = array(
            'headers' => array(
            'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode( Fk-Affiliate-Id . ':' . YOUR_PASSWORD )
            )
        );  



    $api_url = 'https://affiliate.com/api/';
    global $affiliate;
    $response = wp_remote_request( add_query_arg( array(
        'Affiliate-Id' => $affiliate['aff-id'],
        'Affiliate-Token'     => $affiliate['aff-token']
    ), $api_url ) , array( 'timeout' => 10));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send the headers you need by including those in request options - second argument of **wp_remote_request** function(**$args**  in my example)

```
$args = [
    'method' => 'GET',
    'timeout' => 10,
    'headers' => array() //add headers here
];

wp_remote_request('http://test.com', $args);
```